# Translation (Job) Metadata Behavior

Tags: translation-manager, topology-manager, sites-9.1

If configured, Translation Jobs can have metadata fields that will appear to translators in the translation management system as a separate (XML) file.

Question 1:

We can configure multiple [Metadata Schemas in the Translation Manager configuration](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/691568/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/adding-metadata-information-to-translation-jobs) with the caveat that "only one Metadata Schema is allowed per BluePrint hierarchy".

**What does "BluePrint hierarchy" mean in this context? Is that the Publications between a Source and Target?**

Or is that BluePrint hierarchy as an entire stand-alone tree? Where typically there's only *one* BluePrint hierarchy in a given Content Manager, though you could have multiple such trees.

Does this impact the Translation Job screen?

<strike>Does it work like other Metadata Schema drop-downs where the user can choose from a list of configured Metadata Schemas?</strike>

Question 2:

I'm looking for a simple way for a CMS user to share a Staging URL (internally) from a Translation Job to the translator.

I'm aware of the Translation Preview capability and the idea we can (sometimes) programmatically determine the URL for content or pages, assuming a given Component is on a published Page for the given target.

**But do we have programmatic access to the Translation Manager job Metadata?**

I don't think we create an actual Component for the translation job metadata, so Event System wouldn't apply, right?

The desired user story is something like this.

> As someone creating a translation job in the CMS, when available, I would like to automatically determine and share the URL to the Staging website for a given piece of content with my translator. This would save me time for finding and copying the URL into a given Translation Job.

Is Translation Job Metadata a good or possible fit here? If not, what might be an approach to share known URLs with a Translation Job without a full Translation Preview setup? :-)

Comment: I did something similar to get Staging Urls into translation files, https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/translation-preview-tms-mantra-proof-of-concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1:

Indeed only one metadata schema allowed per BluePrint hierarchy.
BluePrint hierarchy in this case means standalone tree.

Answer 2:

You can change metadata using event system

By subscribing to "Item Send" event:

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<ITranslationJob, IItemSendEventArgs>(OnItemSend, EventPhases.Initiated, EventSubscriptionOrder.Normal);
```

You will get one event for every item you send - in theory you can inject ULR in to XML of the actual translated item (I am almost sure it will not break anything if inserted carefully).

You will also get this event for metadata document that we send and you can insert URL there by modifying XML document in ItemRequest.ItemXml property.

Metadata item always has same title "Translation job metadata.its"